# Capistrano error: 'Could not find form_data-0.1.0 in any of the sources' while deploying

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, capistrano

I have a rails application on the dev server and I deleted the shared folder while attempting to make some changes. When I'm trying to redeploy the application, I get the following error on Capistrano.

```
servers: ["xx.xxx.xxx.223"] [xx.xxx.xxx.223] executing command
** [out :: xx.xxx.xxx.223] Could not find form_data-0.1.0 in any of the sources

command finished in 41821ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
* executing "rm -rf /var/www/apps/SITENAME/releases/20150507165055; true"
```

I have tried `bundle install --deployment` and I still get the same error

> Could not find form_data-0.1.0 in any of the sources

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be caused by outdated `Gemfile.lock` file. Remove `Gemfile.lock`, run `bundle install` and try to start your app again.